# How to use Jaggery to get XML and add into Datatables

Tags: jquery, xml, datatable, wso2, jaggery-js

I'm trying to use wsrequest to invoke a data services and display the results in a datatable. I already received the response (following jaggery docs page example), but what I really want is to receive the XML and then create a table to list the records one by one.

How this can be accomplished in jaggery? Does it need to be JSON?

Comment: can you add sample response that your getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I already found a way to it.  Basically I changed it to json which is easier to manage from Javacript.  Thanks